# Define custom model/architecture in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

From the little I have played around with TensorFlow I see it has already-implemented architectures like RNN/LSTM cells, ConvNets, etc. Is there a way to define one's "custom" architecture (e.g. an "enhanced" LSTM network with a few convolutional layers)?

Comment: Voting down an answer with no explanation given. This has become a really annoying trend in SO these days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is totally possible. The output of LSTM or any network are tensors which cab used as input of another network.

See how to combine them at https://github.com/jazzsaxmafia/show_and_tell.tensorflow.

You can find more examples at https://github.com/TensorFlowKR/awesome_tensorflow_implementations.